# Mobile Push test message

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, push-notification

I'm trying to send mobile push test messages through marketing cloud.

How can I add my device ID to mobile push so I can send a test message to only "me", not all of the subscribers? Please kindly share the mobile push notification testing method.
Where can I find my device ID?

Currently, there are no contacts in my account since i haven't linked my contacts yet.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the SDK configured correctly then it will register itself. Once your device is registered you can create an audience list for your device or your contactKey.

Comment: Whre can I find my device key?

Comment: Look in the docs for help: https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/trouble-shooting/trouble-shooting-push-setup.html

Answer (score 3):

You can import a CSV file with a test record, hence you use the new contact for your test send.

Note: your CSV file would need these fields: Contact Key, DeviceID, Platform,   System Token

I put these steps here for your reference:

> 1. Go to Mobile Push: Mobile Studio >> Mobile Push
> 2. On the top right corner: click **Add Contacts**.
> 3. Select the destination for the imported contacts.
> 4. Select the file to upload.
> 5. Before uploading, certify whether you have opt-in permission from contacts in the file.
> 6. Click Next.
> 7. Select the application to associate with the contacts.
> 8. Click Next.
> 9. Map the column headings in the file to the supported MobilePush columns
> 10. Click Next.
> 11. Review the import mapping. Make sure that the column headings match the data in the columns. Click Back to change.
> 12. Enter your email address for notification when the import completes.
> 13. Click Finish.

Reference: [Import Contacts into MobilePush](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_mp_import_contacts_to_a_standard_list_or_into_all_contacts.htm&type=5)

Comment: Whre can I find my device key?

Comment: I thought you already had it. I used to get it from the app, basically the app developer let me an option to see the configured values where I could get the registered Device ID and then I used it for the test

Comment: How do I sort it out as my device among the registered Device ID?